# Convert vector into matrix: New row when value > X

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a question and I can't find any solution, My problem is, that i have a vector `V (m x 1)`. `V` is imported data from excel and can differ in leangth. It contains sequences of numbers >7000 and sequences of numbers < 7000. The sequences also can differ in leangth. Now I want to copy all values that are >7000 into a matrix. Everytime the value of `V` gets >7000 the matrix should start a new row. So that the new rows of the matrix won't differ in leangth, the shorter rows should be "filled up" with 0 until the leangth of the longest row is reached.

This is an example of how it should work.

```
`V [18x1]: [6000, 6500, 5000, 8000, 15000, 15500, 16000, 6000, 4000, 16500, 14000, 400, 5000, 6000, 9000, 12000, 13000, 5000]`

`Matrix [3x4]: 
1.row [8000 15000 15500 16000] 
2.row [16500 14000 0 0] 
3.row [9000 12000 13000 0]`
```

I thought of first splitting the vector into several smaller vectors each time the value of `V` gets > 7000. And afterwards combining them to the desired matrix and delete all values < 7000. But this seems quite inconvenient to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be using `for`:

```
result = []; new_row = 1; col_num = 1; row_num = 0;
limit = 7000;
for idx = 1:length(V)
    if(V(idx) > limit && new_row == 0) % case 1
        result(row_num, col_num) = V(idx);
        col_num = col_num + 1;
    elseif(V(idx) > limit && new_row == 1) %case 2
        row_num = row_num + 1; new_row = 0; col_num = 2;
        result(row_num, 1) = V(idx);
    elseif(V(idx) <= limit) %case 3
         new_row = 1;
    end
end
```

`case 1` is true if before this a row is created and there is no `V(j) < limit` after the row creation.

`case 2` is true if before this `V(idx-1) < limit)`. and `case 3` is true if `V(idx) <= limit`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I tried it and it worked perfect!

Comment: One more point. What do I have to change if I want to fill the end of the rows to a fixed point (for my example let's say up to column 6) with 0? Instead of just until the leangth of the longest row.

Comment: @Chris you need add `row_num` by 1 and set `new_row = 1` when reach to the `col_num == 6`.

Comment: I tried it but I don'know how to implemen it correctly like you meant it. Can you please edit your first post and write the new code with this implemented underneath the original one?

Comment: @Chris Please ask another question, as it is a different question.

Comment: Ok, here is the link to the new quenstion [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815448/turn-vector-into-matrix-when-a-fixed-value-is-reached)