# Turn vector into matrix when a fixed value is reached

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

This question is an addition to this one: [Link to original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810724/convert-vector-into-matrix-new-row-when-value-x)
How can I implement in the code, that all rows should be "filled up" with 0 let's say up to column 6.

This is an example of how it should work.

```
V [18x1]: [6000, 6500, 5000, 8000, 15000, 15500, 16000, 6000, 4000, 16500, 14000, 400, 5000, 6000, 9000, 12000, 13000, 5000]

Matrix [3x4]: 
1.row [8000 15000 15500 16000 0 0] 
2.row [16500 14000 0 0 0 0] 
3.row [9000 12000 13000 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the answer likes the following:

```
result = []; new_row = 1; col_num = 1; row_num = 0;
limit = 7000;
for idx = 1:length(V)
    if col_num == 7
        new_row = 1
    end
    if(V(idx) > limit && new_row == 0) % case 1
        result(row_num, col_num) = V(idx);
        col_num = col_num + 1;
    elseif(V(idx) > limit && new_row == 1) %case 2
        row_num = row_num + 1; new_row = 0; col_num = 2;
        result(row_num, 1) = V(idx);
    elseif(V(idx) <= limit) %case 3
        new_row = 1;
    end
end
if size(result,2) < 6
    result(1,6) = 0;
end
```

Add the follwoing lines to check the `col_num` does not exceed from `6`:

```
if col_num == 7
    new_row = 1
end
```

At the end, check if the column size of the `result` is not `6`, modify the `result` matrix likes the following:

```
if size(result,2) < 6
    result(1,6) = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the inputs:

```
% minimum number of columns in the result matrix
min_cols = 6;

% the output from the accepted answer to your original question
result = [ ...
    8000 15000 15500 16000 ;
    16500 14000 0 0 ;
    9000 12000 13000 0];
```

And here is what you can do to add zeros (append this code to the accepted answer to your original question):

```
% number of columns to add (if min_cols < number of columns in result,
% will not add any extra columns)
cols_to_add = max(0, min_cols - size(result, 2));

% pad with zeros
result = [result, zeros(size(result, 1), cols_to_add)];
```